# AppScript - JSON.parse returns a string

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-apps-script

I am trying to parse a string to a JSON object so that I can then send it to Firebase, but for some reason, it is failing to do so. It is returning a string instead of a JSON object.

Heres my code,

```
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    str = "";
    var Date = data[i][0];
    for(var j = 1; j < columns; j++){
      if(data[i][j] == "")
        data[i][j] = "N/A";
      if(j < columns - 1)
        str += "value" + j + ": " + data[i][j] + ", ";
      else
        str += "value" + j + ":" + data[i][j];
    }

    str = "{" + str + "};";

    str = JSON.stringify(str); //converting to string
    Logger.log(typeof(str)); //returns string

    dataToImport[Date] = JSON.parse(str);
    Logger.log(typeof(dataToImport[Date])); //returns string
    Logger.log(dataToImport[Date]); 
  }
```

This is the output I am getting in Firebase
[image: current]

but I want it something like
[image: desired]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And if you skip the first `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: It showed type of `str` to be `undefined`

Comment: As you seem to have observed, the answer is to build it as an object

Comment: Y wasn't parsing working tho?

Comment: Consider what `JSON.parse` does - it undoes `JSON.stringify`. If you pass a `String` to `JSON.stringify`... what do you get? A `String`, escaped such that when it is parsed by `JSON.parse`, returns the original `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After breaking my head over this issue for an entire night, I finally found a working solution. Instead of forming a string and then parsing it into a JSON object, I've directly formed an array of `str` and then assigned it to array `dataToImport`.

```
for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    var Date = data[i][0];
    for(var j = 1; j < columns; j++){
      if(data[i][j] == "")
        data[i][j] = "N/A";
      str["value" + j] = data[i][j];
    }
    dataToImport[Date] = str;
  }
```